# WCF Trasnport security with certificate client credentials using NetTcpBinding throws error on distributed system

Tags: wcf, certificate, nettcpbinding, transport-security

I want to enable transport security for my Self-Hosted WCF service that uses NetTcpBinding with Certificate as client credential type. The client for this service is a WebAPI. I created certificates using makecert and everything works fine in a single PC. But when I distribute the API and the service to different PCs, I get Certificate errors like "Cannot find Server certificate in Trusted People Store" on the client side even though the certificate is present in the store.

Can someone help me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: The client for this service is a WebAPI? The client for this service can only use NetTcpBinding. Either you didn't mean what you wrote, or that's the problem right there.

Comment: Have your certificate is registered to any `trusted certifying authority`? like VerSign, GoDaddy etc

Answer (score 1):

Store your own certificate in a resources file and read that in , then set the client credential to the certificate you just read.